# Determining the locus of z where $|z-(2+i)|=|z|\sin(\pi/4-\arg(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, locus

The question is simply having to determine the locus (**not the equation, just the conic**) of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ where $z$ satisfies $|z-(2+i)|=|z|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arg(z)\right)$. One method is that involving brute force, writing $z=x+iy ,x,y\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ and simplifying the expression.

Is there any other simpler way to go about this problem. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|z-(2+i)|=|z|\sin(\pi/4-Arg z) \implies \sqrt{ (x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\implies PS=e PM, P(x,y)$$
Here $M$ is the foot of perpendicular at the directrix.
This is a conic with one focus at S(2,1) and directrx as $(x+y)/\sqrt{2}$ and its excentricity $e= 1$. Hence it is a parabola.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y-x)$ on the right side of the equation?

Comment: @Paras Khosla In fact it should be $(x-y)/sqrt{2}$, I have edited the typo, Thanks.